# Controlling rsync with Python?

Tags: python, bash, automation, rsync

I've been wanting to write a python script that would run several instances of rsync in sequence for backing up data to a different computer.

At the moment I just have this text file with the commands I use and I've just been copy-pasting them into the terminal, and it seems kinda silly.

I want to be able to use python to do this for me.  I know very vaguely how to use subprocess.popen, but I have no clue how to get python to interact with rsync directly, like for entering my password for me.  Can python do that?

Something like:

```
if theProccess.proccessResponse == "Password:" :
    theProccess.respond(string)
```

Or is the best that I can do is just have it, or even a bash script, just run the rsyncs in sequence and have to type my password in over and over again?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21):

If you'd like to interact with a subprocess in general, you can use [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect) as mentioned elsewhere.  But for your particular case, assuming your rsync is running over ssh (the default), then you may want to consider setting up a [passwordless ssh](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/152) connection between the two hosts, which will eliminate the need to enter the password.  This is a [key-based solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) and will be much more secure than storing your password in your source code.

[Here's a blogger](http://blogs.oracle.com/jkini/entry/how_to_scp_scp_and) who discusses your exact problem and decides to go with passwordless ssh.

Comment: Just to add to this, you can build a complete working solution by also using the netrc library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/netrc.html) for retrieving the password to be given to pexpect.

Answer (score 7):

There's a great Python module written by Colin Stewart called RSyncBackup that's little known and little documented, but very useful.

By default, it doesn't contain any methods for including a password in your rsync commands, so I modified the module and talked about it in this blog post: http://technofart.blogspot.com/2012/02/rsync-controlled-by-python.html

A link to my modified module can be found in the Download section of my post.

A key-based solution is also a great idea. Also, many rsync implementation will look for the RSYNC_PASSWORD environment variable, which you can set. Just be careful if your environment variables are visible to other users.

Answer (score 6):

I use rsync to back up all of my clients' web sites. A script is triggered by cron and it uses Makefiles for each client because of their different needs.

Rather than do something that enters the password, use ssh-keygen to create a public/private key pair and put your public key on the remote machine. This gives you secure, no-password connections. This also means you don't have to expose the rsync port to the world. After you get past the learning curve on this (and it's not very steep) ssh is most *definitely* your friend.

Comment: I've definitely considered using a key pair for doing this, but I wanted to see if it was possible to have one program control another since it seems like a skill that could come in handy for situations that require interaction and don't have an easy solution to disregard it.  But I may end up doing a keypair anyways...

Answer (score 3):

I feel bad, for answering this late, but I feel like everyone else's answer was wrong.  They did KINDA answer your question, but not directly as they could have.

More to the point, you had asked how to grab the password interactively.  To do so I would suggest the built-in getpass.  In short, you are not interacting with rsync.  You are grabbing the password from the user RIGHT before you execute rsync, and passing that into rsync.  Another option is to allow the user to pass it in as an option, most of my command line scripts use optparse

```
import getpass
password = getpass.getpass('Password for %s: ' % opts.user)
try:
    #code that uses password
except Exception, e:
    # test to see if str(e) is really an invalid password error, if so tell the user and return or loop, up to you
    # else 
    raise Exception(e) # the error that was raised in the first place
```

To continue, I stumbled upon your question because I was looking for something similar.  Just an FYI to anyone else out there, I ended up referencing the two of these stack overflow links:
[calling rsync from python subprocess.call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272582/calling-rsync-from-python-subprocess-call)
and 
[Python Subprocess.Popen from a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984941/python-subprocess-popen-from-a-thread)

Comment: Or using netrc (https://docs.python.org/3/library/netrc.html) to get the password from .netrc file without asking the user to input the password each time, which looks like what the OP is looking for

Answer (score 1):

If you need to programatically control a sub-process, you should look into using [pexpect](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pexpect/).

Comment: This will be relevant to many people: `The main features of Pexpect require the pty module in the Python standard library, which is only available on Unix-like systems.`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it supports rsync out of the box, but [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) might have some components you could recycle?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to enter the password, you can try populating the `RSYNC_PASSWORD` environmental variable or using the `--password-file` option.

Comment: --password-file only works with rsyncd secrets, not your shell password

Answer (score 0):

I've made a python package called parallel_sync that does rsync commands in parallel.
You can use it within or without fabric to perform the operation on multiple hosts at the same time.

It's open source. GNU license.
https://github.com/kouroshparsa/parallel_sync

Feel free to ask for improvements or contribute.

Comment: Where do we find this package? And how is it licensed?

Comment: Since rsync is GPL, this tool should be free software as well ;)

Comment: yes, I've updated my message above. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use asyncssh [SSHClientConnection.run()](https://asyncssh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#asyncssh.SSHClientConnection.run). Asyncssh would be used to connect to your local ssh daemon and then invoke rsync from there. I have not yet tried this but its on my priority list for my internal devops tools.