# Python subprocess rsync using sshpass and specify port

Tags: python, subprocess, port, rsync

I've searched around for quite a bit, finding pieces of what I wish to achieve but not fully. I'm making a sync-script to synchronize files between two machines. The script itself is somewhat more advanced than this question (it provides possibility for both sides to request for file deletion and so on, no "master side").

**First question**

The following bash-command works for me:

```
rsync -rlvptghe 'sshpass -p <password> ssh -p <port>' <source> <destination>
```

how can I translate it into a python command to be used with the subprocess object?

I've managed to get the following python to work:

```
pw = getpass.getpass("Password for remote host: ")
command = ['sshpass', '-p', pw, 'rsync', '-rlvptgh', source, destination]
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
while p.poll() is None:
   out = p.stdout.read(1)
   sys.stdout.write(out)
   sys.stdout.flush()
```

but it doesn't specify port (it uses standard 22, I want another one). To clarify, I wish to use similar code as this one but with the support for a specific port as well.

I have already tried to change the command to:

```
command = ['sshpass', '-p', pw, 'rsync', '-rlvptghe', 'ssh', '-p', '2222', source, destination]
```

which gives the following error:

```
ssh: illegal option -- r
```

and also many other variations such as for instance:

```
command = ['rsync', '-rlvptghe', 'sshpass', '-p', pw, 'ssh', '-p', '2222', source, destination]
```

Which gives the following error (where `<source>` is the remote host source host to sync from, ie variable source above command declaration):

```
Unexpected remote arg: <source>
```

How should I specify this command to nest them according to my first bash command?

**Second question**

When I've done all my searching I've found lots of frowning upon using a command containing the password for scp/rsync (ie ssh), which I use in my script. My reasoning is that I want to be prompted for a password when I do the synchronization. It is done manually since it gives feedback on filesystem modifications and other things. However, since I do 2 scp and 2 rsync calls I don't want to type the same password 4 times. That is why I use this approach and let python (the getpass module) collect the password one time and then use it for all the 4 logins.

If the script was planned for an automated setup I would of course use certificates instead, I would not save the password in clear text in a file.

Am I still reasoning the wrong way about this? Are there things I could do to strengthen the  integrity of the password used? I've already realized that I should suppress errors coming from the subprocess module since it might display the command with the password.

Any light on the problem is highly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I have updated question 1 with some more information as to what I'm after. I also corrected a minor copy + paste error in the python code.

Edit 2 explained further that I do have tried the exact same order as the first bash command. That was the first I tried. It doesn't work. The reason for changing the order was because it worked with another order (sshpass first) without specifying port.

Comment: Why change the ssh to rsync - what happens if you translate the original and not use a different command?

Comment: @Mark I'm not sure exactly what you are asking, but the reason for using sshpass is to be able to pass the password directly in a one-line. ssh has no support for this, nor does rsync (since it normally uses ssh). sshpass can do this, however I haven't found anything in the manual about passing a custom port to the sshpass command.

Comment: The issue is that your working command uses ssh and the non working rsync so how can you expect them to be the same

Comment: @Mark Ahh, I see what you mean now. However, I didn't say that they were equivalent. I just showed the best I was able to do with python to give an indication of what I'm after. I can't seem to modify the specified python command to reflect the first (bash) command I wrote. I will update the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Why change the order of commands - i.e. make rsync the command in the python call i.e. use EXCATLY the same command

Comment: and with ssh why not use private keys etc then no password sent over the wire so will be more secure

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1657700/151019

Comment: @Mark As I wrote I have tried many different variations of the command. I added the exact same order as in the first bash script to the question to indicate that I've tried that order as well. If you mean a different way, please post the correct way as answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: @Mark I have already read that thread. I can't see which part that solves the problem I ask for. I might not understand it properly, if so, please tell me. My script will be executed interactively by a USER manually. It is not automated. If it was, I would have used private keys. I want the user to be prompted for a password in order to be able to execute the script, just as ssh prompts for a password. I just don't want to have to write it FOUR times, but rather just one time. What sshpass does is to give me the possibility to include the password in the connection-string for scp and rsync.

Comment: @Mark I would appreciate if you could elaborate where the security risk for the password passing is. Is it less secure than regular ssh login? Where would you have to be situated in order to see the password? Is there a way to use both private keys and prompted password to make it more safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found one way to solve this for my own needs. It includes invoking a shell to handle the command, which I avoided in the first place. It works for me though, but might not be satisfactory to others. It depends on the environment you want to run the command in. For me this is more or less an extension of the bash shell, I want to do some other things that are easier in python and at the same time run some bash commands (scp and rsync).

I'll wait for a while and if there's no better solution than this I will mark my answer as the answer.

A basic function for running rsync via python with password and port could be:

```
def syncFiles(pw, source, destination, port, excludeFile=None, dryRun=False, showProgress=False):
    command = 'rsync -rlvptghe \'sshpass -p ' + pw + ' ssh -p ' + port + '\' ' + source + ' ' + destination
    if excludeFile != None:
        command += ' --exclude-from='+excludeFile
    if dryRun:
        command += ' --dry-run'
    if showProgress:
        command += ' --progress'
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    while p.poll() is None:
        out = p.stdout.read(1)
        sys.stdout.write(out)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

The reason this works is as I wrote because the invoked bash shell handles the command instead. This way I can write the command exactly as I would directly in a shell. I still don't know how to do this without `shell=True`.

Note that the password is collected from the user with the getpass module:

```
pw = getpass.getpass("Password for current user on remote host: ")
```

It is not recommended to store your password in the python file or any other file. If you are looking for an automated solution it is better to use private keys. Answers for such solutions can be found by searching.

To call the scp-command with password the following python should do:

```
subprocess.check_output(['sshpass', '-p', pw, 'scp', '-P', port, source, destination])
```

I hope this can be useful to someone who wants to achieve what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR

use

> sshpass -f /path/to/your/password/file

instead of -p option.

### My attempt and questions below this line

I meet this problem in 2023, 9 years after you.
The reason maybe come from your password

> sshpass -p pw

I still have no ideal how python handle this pw var, but it seems a little bit  different from bash shell.

I tried

> sshpass -p `cat /home/lee/.password`

but this not work, And I am wondering why.

here is my code

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3.9
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import os
import shlex
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT


def process_sync(params_list):
    for params in params_list:
        cmd = (f"""/usr/bin/rsync -aP --timeout=15 --bwlimit={params['bwlimit']}""" 
               f""" -e "/usr/bin/sshpass -f {params['pwd_file_path']}  ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l {params['user']} -p {params['port']}" """
               f""" {params['source_path']} {params['user']}@{params['host']}:{params['dest_path']}""")
        print(cmd)
        process = Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=1, text=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
        try:
            for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):
                print(line.strip())
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            process.terminate()
            break


def main():
    params_list = [
        {
            'user': 'user',                                         # ssh username
            'port': '22',                                           # ssh port
            'host': '127.0.0.1',                                    # ssh host ip
            'pwd_file_path': '/path/to/your/pwd_file/path',         # ssh password path
            'source_path': '/path/to/your/source/path',
            'dest_path': '/path/to/your/dest/folder',
            'bwlimit': 200,                                         # bandwidth limit KB/s
        },
    ]
    process_sync(params_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```