# Increasing throughput in a python script

Tags: python, unix, python-multithreading

I'm processing a list of thousands of domain names from a DNSBL through dig, creating a CSV of URLs and IPs. This is a very time-consuming process that can take several hours. My server's DNSBL updates every fifteen minutes. Is there a way I can increase throughput in my Python script to keep pace with the server's updates?

**Edit**: the script, as requested.

```
import re
import subprocess as sp

text = open("domainslist", 'r')
text = text.read()
text = re.split("\n+", text)

file = open('final.csv', 'w')

for element in text:
        try:
            ip = sp.Popen(["dig", "+short", url], stdout = sp.PIPE)
            ip = re.split("\n+", ip.stdout.read())
            file.write(url + "," + ip[0] + "\n")
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Show the script - or pseudo-code of the script. This way we can suggest improvements.  A list of thousands in 15 minutes should be easily within the limitations of python.

Comment: +1, please show us what you've got. BTW, if I understood correctly, it's likely that it's name resolution, not the script itself, that's taking so long. If that's the case, you might want to try a threaded solution.

Comment: Regardless of the actual solution, a few pointers: avoid reusing the same variable for different things (text = open...; text = text.read()); use "text.splitlines()" instead of a regular expressions; avoid using "file" as a variable name, since it's a keyword in Python 2.x (though not in Python 3); and remember to close your filehandle (even though Python will do it for you, in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's probably the name resolution that's taking you so long. If you count that out (i.e., if somehow dig returned very quickly), Python should be able to deal with thousands of entries easily.

That said, you should try a threaded approach. That would (theoretically) resolve several addresses at the same time, instead of sequentially. You could just as well continue to use dig for that,  and it should be trivial to modify my example code below for that, but, to make things interesting (and hopefully more pythonic), let's use an existing module for that: [dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org)

So, install it with:

```
sudo pip install -f http://www.dnspython.org/kits/1.8.0/ dnspython
```

And then try something like the following:

```
import threading
from dns import resolver

class Resolver(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, address, result_dict):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.address = address
        self.result_dict = result_dict

    def run(self):
        try:
            result = resolver.query(self.address)[0].to_text()
            self.result_dict[self.address] = result
        except resolver.NXDOMAIN:
            pass


def main():
    infile = open("domainlist", "r")
    intext = infile.readlines()
    threads = []
    results = {}
    for address in [address.strip() for address in intext if address.strip()]:
        resolver_thread = Resolver(address, results)
        threads.append(resolver_thread)
        resolver_thread.start()

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    outfile = open('final.csv', 'w')
    outfile.write("\n".join("%s,%s" % (address, ip) for address, ip in results.iteritems()))
    outfile.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If that proves to start too many threads at the same time, you could try doing it in batches, or using a queue (see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/ for an example)

Comment: Works great, but I keep on getting these errors:



File "/home/okim/dnspython/dns/resolver.py", line 541, in _compute_timeout
    raise Timeout
Timeout

Any ideas?

Comment: Apparently your nameserver is unable to resolve some of the names within the default timeout (possibly the authoritative nameserver is not responding). If you want to skip those, simply change the "except resolver.NXDOMAIN:" line to "except (resolver.NXDOMAIN, resolver.Timeout):". If you want to treat those exceptions differently, just add a new except clause, after the NXDOMAIN one. Incidentally, NXDOMAIN captures non-existent domains.

Comment: BTW, if you find out that the problem is your nameserver, you can specify one nominally with "resolver.default_resolver.nameservers.insert(0, '8.8.8.8')". But I'm just saying it for completeness, it's more likely that, within thousands of domain names, some of them simply aren't responding (especially since you mention they come from a blacklist).

Comment: Yeah, my nameserver has problems. Changing the "except" works though. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The vast majority of the time here is spent in the external calls to `dig`, so to improve that speed, you'll need to multithread.  This will allow you to run multiple calls to `dig` at the same time.  See for example: [Python Subprocess.Popen from a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984941/python-subprocess-popen-from-a-thread) . Or, you can use Twisted ( http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ ).

EDIT: You're correct, much of that was unnecessary.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the need to thread calls to dig. You should put this foremost in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider using a pure-Python library to do the DNS queries, rather than delegating to `dig`, because invoking another process can be relatively time-consuming. (Of course, looking up anything on the internet is also relatively time-consuming, so what gilesc said about multithreading still applies) A Google search for **python dns** will give you some options to get started with.

Comment: the overhead of starting new processes is negligible compared to the time taken to execute a DNS query

Comment: Yes, but the network delay was already covered by gilesc's answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep pace with the server updates, one must take less than 15 minutes to execute. Does your script take 15 minutes to run? If it doesn't take 15 minutes, you're done!

I would investigate caching and diffs from previous runs in order to increase performance.