# How to improve performance through Python multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm new to Python and multithreading, so please bear with me.

I'm writing a script to process domains in a list through Web of Trust, a service that ranks websites from 1-100 on a scale of "trustworthiness", and write them to a CSV. Unfortunately Web of Trust's servers can take quite a while to respond, and processing 100k domains can take hours.

My attempts at multithreading so far have been disappointing -- attempting to modify the script from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089413/increasing-throughput-in-a-python-script) gave threading errors, I believe because some threads took too long to resolve.

Here's my unmodified script. Can someone help me multithread it, or point me to a good multithreading resource? Thanks in advance.

```
import urllib
import re

text = open("top100k", "r")
text = text.read()
text = re.split("\n+", text)

out = open('output.csv', 'w')

for element in text:
        try:
                content = urllib.urlopen("http://api.mywot.com/0.4/public_query2?target=" + element)
                content = content.read()
                content = content[content.index('<application name="0" r="'):content.index('" c')]
                content = element + "," + content[25] + content[26] + "\n"
                out.write(content)
        except:
                pass
```

Comment: Threading in Python is often a wash unless you work around the GIL (e.g. write a Python C extension); in the case above, it may work okay because of the time spent in the IO blocks... anyway, have you considered using a (single-threaded) event-framework like twisted instead?

Comment: As this isn't running on my server, I would prefer doing this without having to install 3rd-party frameworks.

Comment: As might be expected, WOT isn't fond of copying their database in such  a way, and so may start to block your requests (http://www.mywot.com/pl/terms/api )... Maybe you should use their commercial service?

Comment: Also, if you use Jython or IronPython, the problems with the GIL don't apply (it's a C-Python implementation detail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick scan through the WoT API documentation shows that as well as the public_query2 request that you are using, there is a public_query_json request that lets you get the data in batches of up to 100.  I would suggest using that before you start flooding their server with lots of requests in parallel.