# Python subprocess.check_output hangs when executed from thread

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

I am looking to extract the output from some gcloud commands which take some time to execute. When called independently with the subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True) method it works.
However I have tried to speed up this process by using threads. I do not know / understand why the threads get stuck when calling this method.

```
from threading import Thread, Lock
from queue import Queue
import subprocess
import json

class WorkerThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, thread_id, queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = queue
        self.thread_id = thread_id

    def run(self):
        print(f'Started thread {self.thread_id}')
        while True:
            try:
                project = self.queue.get(timeout=1)
                command = f'gcloud iam service-accounts --project={project} list --format="flattened(email)" | awk \'{{ print $2 }}\' | grep -v ^$'
                sa_list = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True).decode('utf-8').splitlines()
                print ('THIS DOES NOT GET PRINTED')
                if sa_list:
                    with lock:
                        data[project] = []
                        for sa in sa_list:
                            data[project].append({'email': sa})
                self.queue.task_done()
            except:
                return

data = {}
q = Queue()
threads = []
lock = Lock()

command = 'gcloud projects list --format="flattened(projectId)" | awk \'{ print $2 }\' | grep -v ^$'
projects = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True).decode('utf-8').splitlines()

for project in projects:
    q.put(project)

for i in range(10):
    t = WorkerThread(i, q)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

q.join()

for t in threads:
    t.join()


with open('results_threading', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
```

I have tried to execute other code inside the thread (instead of subprocess.check_output) and the program seems to run concurrently.

Also found [this old post related to the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984941/python-subprocess-popen-from-a-thread).
Unfortunatly, the author seemed to have found a solution but did not provide any details.

Appreciate any suggestions.Thank You !

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong with this.
The threads hanged because for some commands, the output was empty.
This is because I used *grep -v ^$* to filter for empty lines.
I added *|| true* at the end and this makes the exit code 0 instead of -1, thus allowing the threads to complete the job and fetch the next one from the queue.