# How to trigger from Python playing of a WAV or MP3 audio file on a Mac?

Tags: python, macos, audio

I'm looking for an elegant way, without a ton of dependencies as in some of the solutions I googled up.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know PyGame is the most portable way to play music: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html

You can find its package here: http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml

Answer (score 41):

If you want to do away with external dependencies entirely, and are running OS X 10.5+, you can use the included command-line audio player, [afplay](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/afplay.1.html), along with the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module.

I haven't tested it, but this should work:

```
import subprocess
audio_file = "/full/path/to/audio.wav"

return_code = subprocess.call(["afplay", audio_file])
```

Comment: Tested it. Works great. Simple and effective on OS X. It does freeze the execution, however, while it plays. Perhaps there is an async call for this?

Comment: This works very well for me on Mac OS X El Capitan, with Python 3.5. Thanks so much!

Comment: on linux after installing tool called `sox` above code works if you replace afplay with just play

Answer (score 0):

The leanest most portable way I've found to play .mp3 and .wav files is [playsound](https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound).

```
import playsound

# wait for the sound to finish playing?
blocking = True

playsound.playsound("yourfile.mp3", block=blocking)
```