# Why isn't print(\a) working in IDLE

Tags: python, macos, beep, beepbeep

**NOTE** I changed the q slightly so that it is not a duplicate anymore. Sorry.

I have these time-consuming bioinformatics scripts I am running. I'd like them to sound a beep when they are done.

I am on OS X.

In a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537481/python-making-a-beep-noise) I found that `print '\a'` might work, but in Idle this just prints `[]`

Why does this not work in IDLE

Comment: [How to trigger from Python playing of a WAV or MP3 audio file on a Mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498313/how-to-trigger-from-python-playing-of-a-wav-or-mp3-audio-file-on-a-mac)

Comment: @TheZ: I think using `PyGame`, or even popening `afplay`, is probably overkill for someone looking for a system beep.

Comment: @TheZ Thanks for the link, but I want to avoid having to play a sound-file if I can avoid it.

Comment: @abarnert I was going off of the "I'd preferably like a slightly longer, more offensive beep than the OS X standard" section which sounds like it'd require an external sound.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941/python-sound-bell. Does the second question work?

Comment: @TheUnfunCat No worries, at least you'll have a fallback if nothing else works out :)

Comment: @aychedee I think you are right. Sorry. I really did try searching well.

Comment: @aychedee: The first answer there is the same as what the OP originally tried; the second is the same as my answer; the third is the Carbon equivalent (which will do the same thing as `NSBeep` in 32-bit, nothing at all in 64-bit); the fourth is @TheZ's suggestion. So, there's nothing new there. But I'm not sure whether this is a dup of that question, or the OP's real question is "Why isn't the `\a` solution working in Idle"?

Comment: Changed my q so that hopefully something good can come of it.

Comment: Thanks, you just made my answer look better; instead of clumsily going off on a tangent before answering the original question, it now directly answers the new question and then offers alternatives. If only I could write that way on purpose. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it doesn't beep is that `\a` (or `^G`) is the terminal bell code; it's up to the program handling stdout to turn that into a sound. Terminal.app will play a sound (unless you configure it to do "visual bell" instead, of turn it off entirely), but Idle will not. And, of course, if you're running without a tty, you get nothing.

If you don't mind using PyObjC (which comes pre-installed with the Apple-installed Pythons on all recent versions of OS X):

```
import Cocoa
Cocoa.NSBeep()
```

Of course this plays the OS X system beep, not the Terminal bell. Besides possibly being a different sound, this means if you disable the bell in Terminal, your script will still beep. (If you really want a Terminal bell, you can always script Terminal via, e.g., ScriptingBridge. But I don't think you care.)

Comment: Appreciated, UV, but I would like to avoid importing modules

Comment: You've got a bioinformatics script that works without importing any modules? No `math`, `itertools`, or even `sys`? At any rate, there are no function in the `__builtins__` namespace that will beep, so the terminal bell is your only option given that restriction, which means you will have to run in `Terminal.app` and leave the bell enabled.

Answer (score 2):

This tiny Python snippet using afplay does what I need: ten loud-ish dings at the end of a program:

```
from os import system
for i in range(0,10):
    system('afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Glass.aiff')
```

I presume the overhead of importing system is not small, but it works for me