# How do you make the python bell sound ring more than once?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I started reading about python yesterday. I am reading a book about python for absolute beginners. It is somewhat old, but I got to the part about printing "\a". The book says you could make the program sound the bell multiple times, but my computer only rings it once. I am using Python 2.7.12, and the book uses an earlier version. Is that why? Or does it only work in Python 3? I have Windows 10 on Lenovo laptop.
Right now I have:
    print "\a\a";
    print '\a'
    raw_input("\n\nPress enter to exit")

Comment: On my machine (OSX with Python 2.7.11), `print "\a\a"; print '\a'` causes the bell to ring three times, as expected.

Comment: Just tried that. Didn't work unfortunately. Guess I better be more specific. I am running on Windows 10, with a Lenovo Y50-70 laptop. If that helps at all.

Comment: when you open console, and write following command `echo [Alt-7][Alt-7][Alt-7]` how many beeps do you hear? Alt- left alt key, 7- numeric keyboard 7

Comment: 0 :/ I tried that with ^G too

Comment: @lukbl Ok oops, with ^G three times it only rings once

Answer (score 1):

> > as stated in this answer : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13313492/7091942)
> >
> > The reason it doesn't beep is that \a (or ^G) is the terminal bell code; it's up to the program handling stdout to turn that into a sound. Terminal.app will play a sound (unless you configure it to do "visual bell" instead, of turn it off entirely)

You can also try

> > as stated [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13949/7091942)

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write('\a')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer helps me understand why this isn't working. However, I didn't originally specify that I have Windows. Is there something different for that? Or something I need to install? The sys code only rang one bell again. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think the problem is with the command window itself in windows ( i'm not a very expert in CMD since I'm a Linux user ) maybe there is some configuration for it to sound the bell more than once ? try researching that.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternate way on making a beep sound multiple times:

```
import winsound
Freq = 2500 # Set Frequency To 2500 Hertz
Dur = 1000 # Set Duration To 1000 ms == 1 second
winsound.Beep(Freq,Dur)
winsound.Beep(Freq,Dur)
```

Comment: I'm guessing something is wrong with my python program because I can't even import winsound. The variables don't change colors either.

Comment: Maybe you don't have it installed.Type and run this on a terminal/cmd:
pip install winsound.