# Playing Audio with subprocess.call in Python

Tags: python, audio, subprocess

I wanted to play a .wav file, without using external modules, and i read i could do that using this:

```
def play(audio_file_path):
subprocess.call(["ffplay", "-nodisp", "-autoexit", /Users/me/Downloads/sample.wav])
```

I however get:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If i use `os.path.realpath` to get the absolute path of the file, i get just the same thing. (The path i see at get info)

Environment is OSX, Python 2.7
Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong? I am new to Python (and to Programming).

Comment: related: [Play audio with python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/260738/4279)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems.

- Indentation

  - Code inside the function should be indented, to show that it is part of the function
- File name should be in a quotes

  - It should be a string

It should be:

```
def play(audio_file_path):
    subprocess.call(["ffplay", "-nodisp", "-autoexit", "/Users/me/Downloads/sample.wav"])
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for answering, that fixed it, but i still do not hear the file play. It is .wav ,  and i do not get any errors.

Comment: If you put `ffplay -nodisp -autoexit /Users/me/Downloads/sample.wav` in the terminal, does it work there?

Comment: NameError: name 'ffplay' is not defined

Comment: >>> python ffplay -nodisp -autoexit /Users/me/Downloads/sample.wav
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python ffplay -nodisp -autoexit /Users/me/Downloads/sample.wav
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: is it supposed to say "bash" by default? It does, and error is ffplay: command not found

Comment: @NavedKhan OK, that means that `ffplay` is not installed. Try the instructions at http://www.renevolution.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-mac-os-x/ or try asking at http://apple.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @NavedKhan: have you tried [`afplay` instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3498622/4279)?