# How would I go about playing an alarm sound in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a clock I made and I'd like to make it an alarm clock.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play audio with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260738/play-audio-with-python)

Comment: @Marcelo: sorry I answered, wasn't aware it was a dupe.

Comment: @Rafe: It's no big deal; it happens all the time. Besides, it seems that not too many agree with me. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're on Windows:

```
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound('alert.wav')
```

If you're on Linux (or Mac OS X I believe), you can either use pygame or call a Linux program (like mplayer) using `popen`. pygame example:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

pygame.mixer.music.load("alert.ogg")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
pygame.event.wait()
```

Example using `popen`, which executes a command as if you were in the terminal:

```
from os import popen
cmd = "mplayer alert.ogg"
popen(cmd)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have the `mp3play` module, and plan on playing an MP3 file, you can use this simple method.

```
import mp3play

filename = "C:/PATH/TO/FILE.mp3"
sound = mp3play.load(filename)
sound.play()
```

That code will play the entire MP3 file until it is done. If you want to only play that sound for a certain amount of time, use this:

```
import mp3play
import time

filename = "C:/PATH/TO/FILE.mp3"
sound = mp3play.load(filename)
time.sleep(min(30, sound.seconds()))  # Plays the first 30 seconds of sound.
sound.stop()
```

The `mp3play` module can be downloaded from the [Python package index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=mp3play&submit=search)

Answer (score 0):

On Debian/Ubuntu try this:

```
sudo apt-get install beep
```

and then:

```
import os
os.system('beep')
```