# Playing sound from a specific location in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, audio

**goal**

To play a wav file from the location `D:1.wav`, when the application is started up by the user

**research**

Saw the following questions:

[How would I go about playing an alarm sound in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006709/how-would-i-go-about-playing-an-alarm-sound-in-python)

[Play audio with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260738/play-audio-with-python)

**what I tried**

I tried the following lines:

Example 1

```
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound('D:\1.wav',winsound.SND_FILENAME)  ##Did not work
```

Example 2

```
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound('1.wav',winsound.SND_FILENAME)  ##DID not work
```

Both the times I got the default sound but not the sound that should have played as per the audio file

**also**

1. When I write `winsound.PlaySound('1.wav',winsound.SND_FILENAME)` where does python check for the file `1.wav`? In which directory?
2. Why is the flag `winsound.SND_FILENAME` used for?

**specs** Python 2.7 TKinter 8.5 Windows XP SP

**Please** help me with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
winsound.PlaySound('D:\1.wav',winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

to

```
winsound.PlaySound('D:\\1.wav',winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

to prevent python from escaping your path:

```
>>> a = '\1.wav'
>>> a
'\x01.wav'
```

> winsound.SND_FILENAME
>
> The sound parameter is the name of a WAV file. Do not use with SND_ALIAS.

(From [winsound docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/winsound.html))

If you don't use also the flag `winsound.SND_NODEFAULT`, winsound plays the default sound if it cannot find your specified file.

Create a folder (say `D:\test_sounds\`) with your wav file inside, [add that folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7) to your `PYTHONPATH` variable and try running your code again. Or (better, if you plan to distribute your code), following the same post I just linked, add this to your code:

```
import sys
if "D:\\my_sound_folder" not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append("D:\\my_sound_folder")
```

and then you can just call `winsound.PlaySOund('1.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)` since it will be in your available paths

Comment: i know it says winsound. but i have a question(please oblige if it is too obvious). i use winsound. then i create an exe and then send it to a pc running linux: will it work?? as in will the sound play??

Comment: winsound is only for windows

Comment: yeah. I guessed that but just wanted to be sure. And I even ran it in Linux and found out that it did not work! thanks anyway!

Comment: I tried this but for me too the default sound is triggered. The wav file is in exact directory as is the py file. `winsound.PlaySound("notify.wav",winsound.SND_FILENAME)`. Am I missing something? The path where the wav and py files are are already showing in the list generating using `print(sys.path)`.