# Can windows play sound when I press a keyboard key?

Tags: python, windows

I found [an application](http://www.soundplant.org/) that allows you to do this, and I wondered if this could be done with any built-in programs (I don't mean the Caps Lock, Num Lock radio buttons, their sound can be turned on in the control panel)? This can be done on python with the code below, but my `winsound.PlaySound` doesn’t want to find the file and just plays the system sound of the error. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830045/playing-sound-from-a-specific-location-in-python-tkinter) did not help (either through sys or creating a folder).

The code:

```
import winsound
import keyboard
duration = 250
q = 300
while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            winsound.PlaySound('C:\\some.wav',winsound.SND_FILENAME)            
            winsound.Beep(q, duration)#Since PlaySound does not want to search, you have to do it through squeak
    except:
        break
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't want to find the file"? You always need to tell the program where to find the file, there's no "finding"...

Comment: @h4z3, 
Yes, but even if I specify the path, then mp3 or wav files (different tried) still don't play

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered something similar some months ago in VB.net 
Thus I suggest you to not use the `winsound` but the [simpleaudio](https://pypi.org/project/simpleaudio/) package.

```
import simpleaudio as sa

filename = 'myfile.wav'
wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file(filename)
play_obj = wave_obj.play()
play_obj.wait_done()  # Wait until sound has finished playing
```

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
import simpleaudio as sa


filename = 'music.wav'
wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file(filename)


def on_press(key):
    if key.char == 'q':
        play_obj = wave_obj.play()
        play_obj.wait_done()


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong? I did everything as you said, but after pressing q, the sound does not play and the program ends. `while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):            
            filename = 'some.wav'
            wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file(filename)
            play_obj = wave_obj.play()
            play_obj.wait_done() 
        elif keyboard.is_pressed('w'):
            winsound.Beep(w, duration)
        else:
            pass
       except:
        break`

Comment: added an implementation with key listener