# Tkinter - How can I add a "bell sound" when an event accurs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter

I have a simple question about the bell sounds in Tkinter. How can I add one of them when my progress bar is completed or when I open a message box window with the `filedialog.asksaveasfilename()` function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how-would-i-go-about-playing-an-alarm-sound-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006709)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the method `bell()` to trigger a system bell sound.

*Here is an example how you can play it when the progress bar completes.*

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()

def work():
    if progressbar['value'] == 0:
        but1['state'] = 'disabled'
    if progressbar['value'] >= progressbar['maximum']:
        root.bell()
        but1['state'] = 'normal'
        progressbar['value'] = 0
        return
    progressbar['value'] += 1
    root.after(100, work)

progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(root, length=200, maximum=10, value=0)
progressbar.grid(row=1)

but1 = ttk.Button(root, text='Start', command=work)
but1.grid(row=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Similarly, with the help of this example, I hope you can implement it with message pop-ups as well.

---

The Tkinter `bell()` is the default sound of the operating system, to change the bell sound in the Tkinter application change the system default alert sound. For example,

- [**on macOS,**](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mchlp2207/mac) one can do it by *choosing Apple menu  > System Preferences, click Sound, then click Sound Effects.*

[image]

- Here is [how one can do it on Windows](https://pureinfotech.com/change-notifications-sound-windows-10/).
- Here is [how one can do it on Linux.](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sound-alert.html.en)

Comment: ciao Saad! you have been very clear and thank you so much for having replied with an example. your code works, but I have just realized that you can't play the bell if you lanch your script via CLI. for example, in my code, to play the bell, I had to change the extension of my script from ".py" to ".pyw" (my operating system is Windows 10 Enterprise x64").

Comment: now I have another question, how can I choose a different kind of bell? the default bell doesn't match my scopes

Comment: @TurboC: I ran the code through the command line with and without `.pyw` extension and it is working as it should **though I'm using macOS **. Tkinter bell sound rings the default system alert sound, if you change your system alert sound, it will change in Tkinter apps as well. Like I said as I'm on a mac and I can confirm changing system default sound will indeed change the beep sound in Tkinter apps.

Comment: mm, I see, probably in Windows Tkinter has a different behaviour. but, anyway, so it means that if I want to change the sound raised in "bell()", Tkinter makes me to change the system sound in my operating system? isn't there a simpler way to change the "bell sound"? maybe choosing a different one from the "bell()" function without touch the system settings?

Comment: @TurboC: I don't think if there is a native way of changing bell sound just for the Tkinter applications, but instead you can use other modules like  `pygame`  or `winsound` to change sounds with a `.mp3` file to achieve your goal. [Have a look at this question and its answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006709/how-would-i-go-about-playing-an-alarm-sound-in-python)

Comment: @TurboC: I added some useful information to my answer, check it if this solves your issue and mark this post as *answered* by [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the best answer accordingly.

Comment: ciao Saad, sorry for the late but I was still testing my code. yeah, your answer is good but at the end, as you adviced me, I chosed to use winsound. It's esier because I can choose all system's sounds that I want (all of them in Windows are placed in "C:\Windows\Media"). however using this module means to be dipendent by the system, but.. I will solve this issue when I will complete it. thanks for your support ;)