# Generating sine wave sound in Python

Tags: python, audio

I need to generate a sine wave sound in Python, and I need to be able to control frequency, duration, and relative volume. By 'generate' I mean that I want it to play though the speakers immediately, not save to a file.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: What platform(s) are you targeting?

Comment: Primarily MacOS X - I should have specified this, sorry!

Comment: This question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307305/play-a-sound-with-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260738/play-audio-with-python

Comment: [Sine wave generation](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2007-March/026490.html)

Answer (score 72):

Version with numpy:

```
import time

import numpy as np
import pyaudio

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

volume = 0.5  # range [0.0, 1.0]
fs = 44100  # sampling rate, Hz, must be integer
duration = 5.0  # in seconds, may be float
f = 440.0  # sine frequency, Hz, may be float

# generate samples, note conversion to float32 array
samples = (np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.arange(fs * duration) * f / fs)).astype(np.float32)

# per @yahweh comment explicitly convert to bytes sequence
output_bytes = (volume * samples).tobytes()

# for paFloat32 sample values must be in range [-1.0, 1.0]
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels=1,
                rate=fs,
                output=True)

# play. May repeat with different volume values (if done interactively)
start_time = time.time()
stream.write(output_bytes)
print("Played sound for {:.2f} seconds".format(time.time() - start_time))

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()
```

Version without numpy:

```
import array
import math
import time

import pyaudio

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

volume = 0.5  # range [0.0, 1.0]
fs = 44100  # sampling rate, Hz, must be integer
duration = 5.0  # in seconds, may be float
f = 440.0  # sine frequency, Hz, may be float

# generate samples, note conversion to float32 array
num_samples = int(fs * duration)
samples = [volume * math.sin(2 * math.pi * k * f / fs) for k in range(0, num_samples)]

# per @yahweh comment explicitly convert to bytes sequence
output_bytes = array.array('f', samples).tobytes()

# for paFloat32 sample values must be in range [-1.0, 1.0]
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels=1,
                rate=fs,
                output=True)

# play. May repeat with different volume values (if done interactively)
start_time = time.time()
stream.write(output_bytes)
print("Played sound for {:.2f} seconds".format(time.time() - start_time))

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()
```

Comment: I found @yahweh contribution to be the case. It would be helpful to include in the code sample.

Comment: This doesn't work on my Linux system, it cuts off before it has played all samples, e.g. with duration 2 it plays less than a second. I used the callback method to play all of the samples. Full example here:
https://gist.github.com/FrankBuss/3c2f0d1eaf289ef9f659139b96e7a459

Comment: Doesn't sound like a sine wave to me!

Comment: Looking for a version without numpy dependency.

Comment: Result: `SystemError: PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN macro must be defined for '#' formats`

Answer (score 17):

ivan-onys gave an excellent answer, but there is a little addition to it:
this script will produce 4 times shorter sound than expected because Pyaudio write method needs string data of float32, but when you pass numpy array to this method, it converts whole array as entity to a string, therefore you have to convert data in numpy array to the byte sequence yourself like this:

```
samples = (np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(fs*duration)*f/fs)).astype(np.float32).tobytes()
```

and you have to change this line as well:

```
stream.write(samples)
```

Comment: Very interesting @yahweh. This solves another problem I had. Can you tell me why .tobytes() solves the problem?

Answer (score 4):

One of the more consistent andeasy to install ways to deal with sound in Python is the Pygame multimedia libraries.

I'd recomend using it - there is the pygame.sndarray submodule that allows you to manipulate numbers in a data vector that become a high-level sound object that can be playerd in the pygame.mixer module.

The documentation in the pygame.org site should be enough for using the sndarray module.

Answer (score 4):

Today for Python 3.5+ the best way is to install the packages recommended by the developer.

http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/

For Debian do

```
sudo apt-get install python3-all-dev portaudio19-dev
```

before trying to install pyaudio

Answer (score 1):

The script from ivan_onys produces a signal that is four times shorter than intended. If a TypeError is returned when volume is a float, try adding .tobytes() to the following line instead.

```
stream.write((volume*samples).tobytes())
```

@mm_ float32 = 32 bits, and 8 bits = 1 byte, so float32 = 4 bytes. When samples are passed to stream.write as float32, byte count (duration) is divided by 4. Writing samples back .tobytes() corrects for quartering the sample count when writing to float32.

Answer (score 0):

I the [bregman lab toolbox](http://bregman.dartmouth.edu/~mcasey/bregman/bregman_tutorials/) you have a set of functions that does exactly what you want. This python module is a little bit buggy but you can adapt this code to get your own functions