# How can i make sound with frequency in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, audio, frequency, beep

I tried this, but it didn't made more than an empty line :

```
import os
a=300
b=2000
os.system('play --no-show-progress --null --channels 1 synth %s sine %f' % ( a, b))
```

Comment: Change the `os.system` to `print`, then run the code and copy and paste the string to your terminal.  Does this then play the sound you want?

Comment: The run still gives an empty line. In the terminal the string just prints it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy ways to play a beep sound of given frequency and duration in Python:

```
frequency = 1000 # Hertz
duration  = 2000 # milliseconds
```

On **Windows**:

```
import winsound
winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
```

On **Linux**:

```
# SoX must be installed using 'sudo apt-get install sox' in the terminal
import os
os.system('play -n synth %s sin %s' % (duration/1000, frequency))
```

On **macOS**:

```
# First install Homebrew (https://brew.sh/) 
# and then SoX using 'brew install sox' in the terminal
import os
os.system('play -n synth %s sin %s' % (duration/1000, frequency))
```

**Cross-platform**:

Using `PyAudio` module and a bit of coding: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27978895

Comment: play WARN sox: Option `-f' is deprecated, use `-e floating-point' instead.
play WARN getopt: option `l' not recognized
play:      SoX v14.4.1

play FAIL sox: invalid option

Comment: On which platform are you, and which solution did you try?

Comment: On Ubuntu with the second solution.

Comment: I updated my answer with a more general Linux solution. Now it should work (I tested it on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS)

Comment: Thank you it works :) And I got a small heart attack XD