# Sound generated in pyAudio doesn't work in Pygame

Tags: python, audio, pygame, pyaudio

I followed the code from this previous question: [Generating sine wave sound in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299303/generating-sine-wave-sound-in-python?rq=1), with the added line `var = stream.write(volume*samples)`. I tried to use this variable in pygame `sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(var)` but I get the error `TypeError: Unrecognized argument (type NoneType)`. I'm unsure why this is happening, and how I can get around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because `mixer.Sound` takes a Sound Object or Buffer Object, and you are giving it a numpy array.