# Smoothly transitioning audio sinewave using python

Tags: python, audio, wave, pitch

I‘m a python noobie and I‘m looking to create a sinewave tone generator in python.
I would like it to transition smoothly (between frequencies) in realtime.

Pseudo-Code:

`i = 1
 while i <= 1000:
   play(frequency_hz = i)
   i =+ 1`

You would hear a low pitch transitioning to a high pitch.
It would be dope if this could be non-blocking so whatever frequency_hz is dropped in would automatically play continuously.

i.e.: [Sinewave smooth transition](https://www.szynalski.com/tone-generator/)
you move the slider and you hear a transitioning pitch based on the slider (frequency_hz)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating sine wave sound in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299303/generating-sine-wave-sound-in-python)

Comment: It kinda does, but when I vary the frequency, I hear popping sounds presumably because there is no cross-fade or smooth transition.