# PyQt4 QtGui.QSound play as a command line program?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, audio

How might one blast QSound from a command line?

Under PyQt4, playSound.py could be as simple as this:

```
QtGui.QSound('start.wav').play()
```

Except it doesn't play without an .exec() style event dispatcher available.

So what's the simplest dispatch queue that doesn't pop a window up and quits on time?

Answer (score 1):

`QSound` doesn't have a reliable and portable way to signal when the sound is done.

You could use phonon instead ([code example in C++](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/phonon-overview.html#audio)) and connect the `MediaObject::finished()` signal to the `quit()` slot of the application.

Comment: and a tiny app only used to exec. K at least phonon is built-in, unlike a few other sound drivers we could also mention!

Answer (score 1):

Why using PyQt for a CLI app? It seems overkill, you should embrace Python's batteries and use PyQt for the UI, that way is more portable if you need both CLI and GUI versions.

There are plenty of options for playing audio in plain Python. [1]

[1] http://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio/

Also check these here on SO:

[Play audio with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260738/play-audio-with-python)

[Play a Sound with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307305/play-a-sound-with-python)

Comment: Because we're building a PyQt4 app, so the ground rule is "prefer PyQt4 over any other library if at all possible"

Answer (score 1):

The following standalone code works fine for me, without any windows popping up:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
s = QtGui.QSound('test.wav')
s.play()
while not s.isFinished():
    sleep(0.1)
```

The `s.isFinished()` check is required because otherwise the script will immediately exit without having played the wav, because `play()` doesn't block.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsound.html

Answer (score 0):

from PyQt4.QtGui import QSound

QSound.play("Filename")