# Python Random Audio

Tags: python, audio

I have no experience working with audio, and I am looking for some direction on where I could find music that when a button is clicked in python it will play a random song from a selection of some. I have already written a program for my aunt, and I am trying to add audio to the program. She is a devout catholic, and I would like to use catholic songs. I have spent the past hour searching for information on python audio but have not found anything of use. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what have you found in your hour of searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to play music is to use Pygame. It has two modules that are related to playing music which are pygame.mixer and pygame.music. [Here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html) is the link to the Pygame music module. Also you can look at [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260738/play-audio-with-python) thread where people discuss their recommendations for Python and music.