# Play sound effect when you press a Button in Tkinter

Tags: python, image, user-interface, audio, tkinter

How can I get sound effects when I press buttons on the GUI for Tkinter?

Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk() #root object for the buttons
from PIL import Image, ImageTk #python imaging library

#open the images and store them in photos
image = Image.open("Jolteon.PNG")
image1 = Image.open("Eevee.PNG")
image2 = Image.open("Vaporeon.PNG")
image3 = Image.open("Flareon.PNG")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image) 
photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2)
photo3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image3)

topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root) #some different frames
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

button1 = Button(topFrame, text="Eevee", fg="brown")
button2 = Button(topFrame, text="Jolteon", fg="yellow")
button3 = Button(topFrame, text="Vaporeon", fg="blue")
button4 = Button(topFrame, text="Flareon", fg="red")
button5 = Button(topFrame,image=photo)
button6 = Button(topFrame,image=photo1)
button7 = Button(topFrame,image=photo2) #sdbsdfbdfsbdfb
button8 = Button(topFrame,image=photo3)

#packages the buttons so that it can be produced
button1.pack()
button6.pack()
button2.pack() #sdbsdbsdbsdfbfdsn
button5.pack()
button3.pack()
button7.pack()
button4.pack()
button8.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It displays names and pictures of the `Eevee trios` from Pokemon.
What I want is when I press the picture of the pokemon to make the pokemon cry.

How would I go on about implementing this?

[image]

Comment: More info about playing sounds can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/260738/3714930). If you have a function that plays the sound (say `eeveeSound()`) just use the `Button`'s `command=eeveeSound` option to bind it to that function.

Answer (score 2):

You have to link the click of your mouse on the image, with an even handler (or simply method):

```
btn = tkinter.Button(root, text='Play Sound', width=16, bg='#2ff')

btn.bind('<Button-1>', on_click)  
# binding the click of btn with the on_click function 

btn.pack()

# note the parameter 'event', since this is a even handler
def on_click(event): 
    # play music
```

You could use the `pygame` module, and specifically you could use its [mixer](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html) module for playing music. You could easily install the `pygame` module for your version of Python and for Windows from the [official website](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml).

Once the installation is finished, you have first to initialise the `Pygame modules` with this command `pygame.init()`. Remember to uninitialize the same modules once you stop using them with the command `pygame.quit()`. Note that you can initialise single modules, like the `mixer` module, which is the exact one that you should use.