# How do I play a .wav file using Tkinter on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, audio, tkinter, wav

I am trying to get a laughing track to play whenever you die in my text adventure game, I am using Python but since I have no clue how to use Tkinter on Python. I never used TKinter so I need some help. If you are wondering where the file is, It is in a folder I named **Sound Files**.

Comment: The [TKinter help page has a HelloWorld](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html), did you try it?

Comment: Search web or pypi.python.org for something like 'python play sound'.  The sound functions in pygame are one possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Use winsound - it's built in.

```
import winsound

winsound.PlaySound('laugh.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will wager a guess and say there is not built-in facility for playing audio. I would suggest reviewing older answers to similar question: [Play audio with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260738/play-audio-with-python)

**UPDATE**

I see I was wrong. Python 3 appears to have some facilities: [22. Multimedia Services — Python 3.5.1 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mm.html)

Comment: I believe you were right the first time.  The 'audio' modules read and write sound files in various formats, but do not play them through a speaker (unless writing to a sound device works).