# how to play ogg stream url in python?

Tags: python, ogg, watson

I have processed some audio file, but i only have a URL like this:

```
 https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?voice=en-US_LisaVoice&text=How%20can%20I%20help%20you%20today.&watson-token=r4H7NZRIVbmROHTbd6Bw6NskKwtLAmowO1Roz%2F2e0HzvdkV7iFxJGKnI8Yk%2BWRL13lBppUzSyef1gRjL2gMuQeAu%2BkEgC9JX9G9hG6sedhvC6FHVIlsWsykkjcWsP%2FxBUzXujYdOJHNoTXoDK2MOZAsD%2F155m44REIZYsyWWk7Pnl9fJNjfZQlu4lIMt38VIJKNq9UXBlTB%2FibSW57H7yRGuoEw0RUrAd6oDSt0qYEewEm0Qr6azD98HeL0NjKRcgiiEpJIwJNyXr6mwYFT7bMpq2qswZD56GtgrXkDoF2NZqi2snSk4XzFubSQsO0oE95bs3jm4VPLukQKnyDD9T63P%2B3%2FVhFokRP%2BA8%2BZ%2FITQu%2FYLo3p6juVTUsXGPL5dEU7JmHpuFSqfQQ%2FHiKJTkJiVRZJ%2B0bjoj9yzy3iDQ%2BEGhKzLxng%2BxOX7qkpoo8DVRUrGrnuCoHaQ04OmS10Ic8AVMVvgYmoJOJ8gntCBDwO5ucjn9xVpkONmzHB%2FJs6NJ%2FJc%2BYkOJsKvo2SNW39U2lE8Mrj2Q%2F0XjPzVKQ%2B40oP2oRPDA0RpvXe09Ka1JHFczt5sxQ8W8YJcKUyXJkmlZ%2FGWnmSDG17Yr4LuolUjnn38lNzhn026VwrQ7LqVYVKoc8hmfwxTDr%2BAuL%2Bv4TYGYW75JJNVzdPN5mgbI32a%2F15YHSnykpCECTQ1PzOT3TaaCu41qV6wsqHCCd%2FaGF3jsvUo%2BWQWDZq%2FM0fkbnsyYaHyOO4AAkm9nADnRiD%2FLLuoHERtuay2YhsyJKagNU4YXJ0ISakxfFvs9K1OnLIRInYliWW84DVDVLLnJHhOBFMUH4vytECdAh2%2BNlwDE2GnzgHDg9QSieItFLnYC6tp2BLSL02502%2Fjv1sw4TEfWETCcTwsK8zPc8g%2F3KX7Pwf24ZgUcjzfXtZiwjVc70vPQsxjxTzLqTzP7Mo61QLmSOkFL&accept=audio%2Fogg
```

It seems like a stream url, so how can i play it directly instead of saving as a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests
url = "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?voice=en-US_LisaVoice&text=How%20can%20I%20help%20you%20today.&watson-token=r4H7NZRIVbmROHTbd6Bw6NskKwtLAmowO1Roz%2F2e0HzvdkV7iFxJGKnI8Yk%2BWRL13lBppUzSyef1gRjL2gMuQeAu%2BkEgC9JX9G9hG6sedhvC6FHVIlsWsykkjcWsP%2FxBUzXujYdOJHNoTXoDK2MOZAsD%2F155m44REIZYsyWWk7Pnl9fJNjfZQlu4lIMt38VIJKNq9UXBlTB%2FibSW57H7yRGuoEw0RUrAd6oDSt0qYEewEm0Qr6azD98HeL0NjKRcgiiEpJIwJNyXr6mwYFT7bMpq2qswZD56GtgrXkDoF2NZqi2snSk4XzFubSQsO0oE95bs3jm4VPLukQKnyDD9T63P%2B3%2FVhFokRP%2BA8%2BZ%2FITQu%2FYLo3p6juVTUsXGPL5dEU7JmHpuFSqfQQ%2FHiKJTkJiVRZJ%2B0bjoj9yzy3iDQ%2BEGhKzLxng%2BxOX7qkpoo8DVRUrGrnuCoHaQ04OmS10Ic8AVMVvgYmoJOJ8gntCBDwO5ucjn9xVpkONmzHB%2FJs6NJ%2FJc%2BYkOJsKvo2SNW39U2lE8Mrj2Q%2F0XjPzVKQ%2B40oP2oRPDA0RpvXe09Ka1JHFczt5sxQ8W8YJcKUyXJkmlZ%2FGWnmSDG17Yr4LuolUjnn38lNzhn026VwrQ7LqVYVKoc8hmfwxTDr%2BAuL%2Bv4TYGYW75JJNVzdPN5mgbI32a%2F15YHSnykpCECTQ1PzOT3TaaCu41qV6wsqHCCd%2FaGF3jsvUo%2BWQWDZq%2FM0fkbnsyYaHyOO4AAkm9nADnRiD%2FLLuoHERtuay2YhsyJKagNU4YXJ0ISakxfFvs9K1OnLIRInYliWW84DVDVLLnJHhOBFMUH4vytECdAh2%2BNlwDE2GnzgHDg9QSieItFLnYC6tp2BLSL02502%2Fjv1sw4TEfWETCcTwsK8zPc8g%2F3KX7Pwf24ZgUcjzfXtZiwjVc70vPQsxjxTzLqTzP7Mo61QLmSOkFL&accept=audio%2Fogg"
r = requests.get(url)

with open("download.ogg", "wb") as o:
    o.write(r.content)
```

You can create an in-memory file with `StringIO(r.content)` (or `BytesIO` in Python3) but you must find a library that will play from a file-like object instead of a real file.

For more details on that, see here: [Play audio with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260738/play-audio-with-python)

Comment: tks, it's works.but i want to play it directly instead of save as a file,so do you have some good idea?

Comment: You can create an in-memory file with `StringIO(r.content)` (or BytesIO in Python3) but you must find a library that will play from a file-like object instead of a real file.

Comment: upvoting as this best answers the OPs request.

Answer (score 0):

First I would recommend to use the [Python WDC SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk) to process the information for you.

For example:

```
from watson_developer_cloud import TextToSpeechV1

voice = 'en-US_LisaVoice'
message = 'How can I help you today.'
audio_type = 'audio/ogg'

username='...'
password='...'


tts = TextToSpeechV1(username=username, password=password) 
response = tts.synthesize(message, accept=audio_type,voice=voice)
```

The response object contains your audio.

If you are using [Jupyter notebooks](https://jupyter.org), you can use the `IPython.display.Audio` like so:

```
from IPython.display import Audio
Audio(response)
```

(Note: doesn't work on OSX Safari for some reason)

For general Audio libraries for python, see this answer.

[Play audio with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260738/play-audio-with-python)

Comment: thanks,but i know how to do by using WDC, but now i only have the url.

Comment: So what has this to do with python?

Comment: oh, I want to find how to play this audio URL in python

Comment: The URL is pointing to your audio. The `r.content` in @PauloScardine answer is your audio content. So you just run that through an audio library mentioned in link above.