# terminating a thread that plays a ringtone in a voip app

Tags: python, multithreading

I need threading for a voip app that I am writing in python and PyQt5. This thread does the playing ringTone job.
But I don't know how to stop this thread from playing, I need a way like `terminate` in Process to kill the thread clean and easy but I couldn't find that. I have to mention that I can't use Process and multiProcessing (there is a problem that I couldn't find a way to show that in minimal way).

Here is a minimalized code for my problem:

```
import playsound
# from multiprocessing import Process
from playsound import playsound
from threading import Thread


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ringTone = True
    def ringTonePlay(self):
        while self.ringTone:
            playsound("ring_tone.wav")

    def testFunction(self):
        self.p1 = Thread(target = self.ringTonePlay)
        self.p1.start()

    def stopFunction(self):
        self.ringTone = False


test = Test()
test.testFunction()
test.stopFunction()
```

When I call `stopFunction` function it still keeps ringing.
What way you suggest for terminating the playing thread??

Comment: You cannot kill threads. Does the thread stop *eventually* after calling ``stopFunction``, once the wav has finished playing? How long is the wav?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi No it doesn't stop..But i need a way to stop the thread..I want the wav to be played until i want

Answer (score 0):

You can use [threading.Event](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects). You can block and unblock the thread as you like.

**Edit:** If `playsound` plays the given sound in a different thread, you might need to check the documentation on how to stop/block it.

Example:

```py
import playsound
import threading
from playsound import playsound

class Ringtone(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.threadID = threadID
      self.name = name
      self.event = threading.Event()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.event.wait()
            playsound("ring_tone.wav")

ringtone = Ringtone(1, "Ringtone")
ringtone.start()

# To block the thread
ringtone.event.clear()

# To unblock the thread
ringtone.event.set()
```

Comment: sounds good..but how can i kill the thread? because in this way the thread isn't killed and the app is still running

Comment: The code in the question already checks a flag in the ``while`` loop to see if it needs to stop. Waiting for an event will not stop the sound if the exiting the ``while`` loop did not stop it either.

Comment: Well, killing threads is **not** recommended. Take a look at this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325528/9250756) Killing the thread might cause hazards like file locks, deadlocks etc. The library used in the question is old and uncomplete. It doesn't provide a **proper** way to stop the playback. You might want to check other packages so take a look at this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/260738/9250756)