# How can I add sounds after winning the memory puzzle game?

Tags: python

If I want to add sounds after winning memory puzzle game, what code should I put?

I want to add a code insert to the line and have sounds after winning the game, but I don't know where should add and what should I add.

This is the website for the all code and http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/chapter3.html

Comment: Welcome to SO. This was answered here before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260738/play-audio-with-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play audio with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260738/play-audio-with-python)