# There is no sound generated when using PlaySound(),simpleaudio,pygame,winsound in python

Tags: python

I want to play a sound using playsound module or any other type of sound playing package but there is no sound being emitted and the program is perfectly correct there is no error. I tried everything but there seems to be no result
the code is as follows

```
import playsound from playsound
playsound('abcd.mp3')
```

here is a screenshot:https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2o2O.jpg

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Comment: im on windows =)

Comment: Your code should be ok if you see no errors. Bad indentation or wrong mp3 directory both give errors when running.

Comment: its really strange

Comment: Can you play and hear abcd.mp3 outside python in mediaplayer or something.

Comment: yes i can play it

Answer (score 1):

Might be your way of writing a syntax is wrong Try this:

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('abcd.mp3')
```

Comment: yeah it is like that if you can see the screenshot ,im new to stackoverflow and couldent get all of it to be in code ':(

Comment: @rovvan if you run the code that you have show us in screenshot you will get `IndentationError`

Comment: @rovvan just run the above code that i have provide and then see

Comment: `import playsound from playsound` this is not the valid way to import

Comment: i changed it and still nothing

Comment: @rovvan it's strange. You should properly check your audio device by playing an audio manually

Comment: yes it is , i think it has something to do with the audio file not being found or something like that

Comment: @rovvan if your program cannot find the file that you specified it will through and error `Cannot find the specified file.  Make sure the path and filename are correct.` like that but in your case it doesn't through an error

Comment: its weird really

Answer (score 1):

You have place the **audio file abcd.mp3** in the **folder(sop\venv\ )** where your **game.py** file stored and then you run this command to get the audio

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('abcd.mp3')
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes i think it is something to do with the audio file because the file abcd.mp3 dosent appear when writen , and although i did as you suggested there is still no sound

Answer (score 1):

Your code is written in a little bit strange way, try like that:

```
from playsound import playsound

playsound("abcd.mp3")
```

hence invert the from and the import and remove the indentation of the second line of code.

In my case it works.

Comment: its says its correct but there still is no sound playing

Comment: You can check other options in the answer to that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260738/play-audio-with-python

Comment: Also check that by playing it manually the mp3 audio plays normally

Comment: the audio plays normally and ill check out other options

Comment: i have tried simpleaudio and there is still no audio being played :(

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments:

Your syntax is correct otherwise you'll get an error.
Your mp3 can be found otherwise you'll get an error.
Your mp3 plays with sound in another app.

Try this to see if it produces a sound:

```
import winsound
frequency = 2500  # Set Frequency To 2500 Hertz
duration = 1000  # Set Duration To 1000 ms == 1 second
winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
```

Comment: Did you try this?